# How to select string contains all substring in JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I want to select string from table that contains ALL substrings. For example, I have table CAR_DESCRIPTION that contains raws in colum Desc for example:

```
tesla is super car

bmw is cool car

opel is budget car
```

And I want to select first raw (tesla is super car) by this substring (tesla, car).

I try to use:

```
findAllByDescIn(final Set<String> words);
```

but i get all this raws because all of them contains word car.

Comment: I need to select from DATA BASE

Answer (score 0):

I done it.

Where word something like: "test cool car".

```
private List<Phrase> find(final String word) {
final StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();

Arrays.stream(word.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .forEach(s -> {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(words.toString())) {
                words.append("%").append(s);
            } else {
                words.append("%").append(s).append("%");
            }
        });

return repository.findAllByEngIn(words.toString());
```

}

```
//Need to put words like %car%cool%
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM Phrases as p WHERE p.eng LIKE (:words)")
List findAllByEngIn(final String words);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a `Set<String>` from which you want to get all Strings that contain the substring "car", I assume. For this, you can iterate over the entire set, and only select the Strings that contain your desired substring:

```java
public Set<String> getSubsetThatContains(Set<String> input, String sub) {
    Set<String> output = new HashSet<>();
    for (String string: input) {
        if (string.contains(sub)) {
            output.add(string);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I need to select from DATA BASE

Comment: Question was about how to select from DB, not just from string. And need to compare all substring from Set for finding string.